# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined variable competitionData

Tags: php

I got this error. Anyone can solve it? Im really need help.

This is the code for view :

```
<div class="list-group">      
   <?php 
      if($competitionData) {
          $x = 1;
          foreach ($competitionData as $value) { 
      ?>
      <a class="list-group-item classSideBar <?php if($x == 1) { echo 'active'; } ?>" onclick="getcompetitionvenue(<?php echo $value['competition_id'] ?>)" id="competitionId<?php echo $value['competition_id'] ?>">
      <?php echo $value['competition_name']; ?>(<?php echo $value['numeric_name']; ?>)
      </a>  
   <?php 
      $x++;
   }
} else {
   ?>
      <a class="list-group-item">No Data</a>
   <?php
      }   
   ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Errrr... on which "line"?

Comment: Please paste the whole file, it seems there is no initialization of the variable `$competitionData`

Comment: `foreach ($competitionData as $value)` means that's coming from an array somewhere; "you" have that.

Comment: $competitionData variable is not defined, Share whole file

Comment: hi @Fred-ii-, can you past your email as you can help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set $competitionData you need to initialize it to something first such as $competitionData = true; before you try and use it. Another option would be to replace:

```
if($competitionData) {
```

with:

```
if(isset($competitionData)) {
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: in which file that I should implement this?

Comment: I can't say as I am not writing your project but it looks like you should be setting $competitionData to an array as it is trying to output them in HTML. I will update my answer with another option.

Comment: Please can you mark my answer as the accepted one?